Failed to expand the storage of "Computer" in Ubuntu 22.04?
I'm new to Ubuntu(Ubuntu is a dual system installed with Windows 11 on the same computer) and noticed that there is only 13.7 GB of free space available in "Computer." Therefore, I want to expand this storage of "Computer"(refer to image 3)
To allocate more space to "home," I expanded the disk mounted to "home" to 160.08 GB using gparted. However, "Computer" still shows only 13.7 GB of free space(refer to image 1,2,3).
I suspect I may have expanded the wrong disk or made an error during the expansion process. Could you please guide me on how to correctly allocate more free space to "Computer"?
Thanks for your help!
Image 1:
my filesystem

Image 2:
My disks

Image 3:
The "Computer" that I want to expand

Image 4:
/etc/fstab


You have 2 Ubuntu partitions, one for / and one for /home. Computer is showing the state of the / partition. For new users of Ubuntu i recommend the default partition scheme used by the installer of a single / partition with no other partitions. If you want to expand the / partition, you will have to boot from a live USB and shrink the /home partition.

Do you have /home mounted in fstab? Post in question:  cat /etc/fstab

@user68186, thank you for replying. Yes, there are two partitions in my Ubuntu. However, as you can see, that "/" is on the disk "/dev/nvm1n1p4",  which has around 47.68 GB space. This is smaller than the 50.1GB of "Computer". Could you explain, why it shows "50.1 GB"?

@oldfred, thanks for your reply. I have added "fstab" into the post. I think, it shows, I have mounted "/home".

Different apps measures disk size differently. 1 kilobyte is 1024 bytes. However, hard disk manufacturers typically use 1 kilobyte = 1000 byte. That's why 50.1GB=47.68GB. By the way, we are talking about partitions here, not disks. Your computer has two "disks" or SSDs that is referred to as nvme0n1 and nvme1n1. The p1, p2, ... p8 suffixes are partitions of the SSD or "disk".

You show two mounts of /boot in fstab. Most desktops do not need a separate /boot partition, but many with servers or LVM often for full drive encryption use a /boot partition.

Thank you two. It's solved.
